# Downloading Qt 4.8.3

Tags: qt, download

I haven't used Qt for months. But now when i want to download the latest version, I can't find the download for the last version in Qt project website there is only Qt SDK with version 4.8.1 but in the commercial version website there is 4.8.3.

so where can I download Qt SDK with Qt 4.8.3 for linux (ubuntu) ? please

---

I have installed the SQK with apt-get i just, and i downloaded Qt 4.8.3. what i need now is the instruction to compile it with MySQL plugins.
there is a file in the download that points to the old qt.nokia.com website so i can't find these instructions.

Comment: I would say use the ones from your distribution to save headaches, but that is also only at 4.8.1. It may show up in time as I see other distributions are already including it.

Answer (score 2):

http://qt-project.org/downloads

try this link it might work

The details about 4.8.3 are also given in the link. I'm using Qt creator it is working fine for me.

Comment: it the i was in and they say the SDK has version 4.8.1, so do i use the links in the bottom and download the library and QtCreator separately ?

Answer (score 0):

Note for Qt 4.6.3 and Qt 4.7.3 development
Qt SDK 1.2 contains only the latest targets for developing applications for Symbian platforms. If you wish to work with Qt 4.6.3 for Symbian or Qt 4.7.3 for Symbian^3 and Symbian Anna please use Qt SDK 1.1.2. Once you have installed Qt SDK 1.1.2, to enable use of the earlier targets and App TRK, don’t run the SDK update as this will remove the features you need.

Please be aware that if you want to use the Qt SDK 1.1.2 and Qt SDK 1.2.1 on the same computer, you should install them into separate user accounts.

Qt SDK 1.1.2 can be found here.

This is what mentioned in the site. I think there is no such version for Qt SDK